# Central limit theorem and fluctuations

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, critical-phenomena

Considering a statistical model away from its criticality, the system can be essentially viewed as a collection of subsystems of size $\xi^d$ (with $\xi$ the correlation length) with no mutual interaction. Then, according to the central limit theorem, the fluctuations of any observables at large distances should all have a Gaussian probability distribution. Is this statement true?

Comment: What do you mean by "at large distances"?

Comment: By "large distances" I mean that correlations at distance $r \gg \xi$